# Could not create task ':<package_name_here>:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native

We have a react-native app, and it runs on my friends computer very well. But in my computer only ios works and when trying to build on android it gives error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tasks'.
> Could not create task ':lottie-react-native:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
   > No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARNİNG

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 13s
```

and i tried the run on android studio too, it gives a similiar error :

```
Multiple build operations failed.
    Could not create task ':lottie-react-native:compileDebugKotlin'.
    Could not create task ':react-native-avoid-softinput:compileDebugKotlin'.
    Could not create task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'.
    Could not create task ':react-native-pager-view:compileDebugKotlin'.
    Could not create task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin'.
    Could not create task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.
    Could not create task ':react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin'.
Could not create task ':lottie-react-native:compileDebugKotlin'.
No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARNİNG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try kotlin lastest version. this method worked for me kotlinVersion = '1.9.0' classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0"